# What algorithm could be used to move from a position across a two-dimensional array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Since last night I have been working with two-dimensional array in C and have obtained a random position (x) and (y) in my matrix NxN and I have assigned the value '1' (matrix [x] [y] = 1).

It turns out that my matrix in all its cells contains the number '0' and several '1'. But there is a '1' generated after the random position (this I have already developed).

[image: Initial matrix]

Then you need some idea or algorithm, for that random starting position to fill all other cells that have '0' in the matrix. I know I must move in 8 directions within the adjacency matrix cell 1 to 1.

[image: Directions]

I have a theory to solve it, but not if it is correct, I explain:

If my position would be random (x, y) then the movements to be made are:

Right (x, y + 1).

Up (x-1, y)

Top-Right (x-1, y-1).

..and so on..

Assuming that to be right, could go that way this whole matrix and where there is a '0' put '1' ?, but that iterative or recursive algorithm could work for me?

regards

Comment: If you are you looking for a floodfill algorithm, there is only a need to consider 4 directions.

Comment: [Flood Fill wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Comment: Language-agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some arrangements and it works. Someone thinks you can improve?

```
void floodFillUtil(int screen[][N], int x, int y, int prevC, int newC, bool ini)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= M || y < 0 || y >= N)
        return;                   

    if ( (screen[x][y] == newC  &&  prevC != newC) || (screen[x][y]== prevC && !ini ) )               
        return;        

    if( screen[x][y] != prevC )
         screen[x][y] = newC;

    floodFillUtil(screen, x+1, y, prevC, newC, false);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x-1, y, prevC, newC, false);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x, y+1, prevC, newC, false);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x, y-1, prevC, newC, false);    

    floodFillUtil(screen, x-1, y+1, prevC, newC, false);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x-1, y-1, prevC, newC, false);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x+1, y-1, prevC, newC, false);
    floodFillUtil(screen, x+1, y+1, prevC, newC, false);
}
```

thanks to all